# Dynamic text box generation from drop down list(C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Im using C# in VS 2010 to develop a web page.

the below is what i used to develop the dynamic text box for a certain drop down option...the problem im facing is that the text box is not being generated when i select the option.It is generated only when i clik a button or do some activity.

What changes should i do OR where to place the code to generate the text box as soon i select the option in the drop down control

```
        TextBox new_textbox = new TextBox();
        new_textbox.ID = "txt" + 1;
        new_textbox.Text = "";
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new_textbox);
        Label5.Visible = true;
```

Comment: Is that code fired when the selected index of your drop down changes?

Comment: Debug and see what property `new_textbox` has a value that might cause the issue (for example: location, visibility, size)

Comment: sry,i didn get u. what is the problem in that?

Comment: yes it is in "DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged"

Comment: As Abe says.  Where in your code is that piece fired?   is it on DDL changed? or happening only on postback?   You would still be better off doing this with jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set AutoPostBack="True" in your dropdownlist

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
```

When AutoPostBack Property is set to 'true' a postback to the server occurs automatically  whenever the user selects an item from the list. By default it is set to 'false'.